# VS code can not open any other emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to open my emulators from android studio to VS code for my flutter project. I install like 5-6 different emulators but vs code recognize them only when i open android studio and start them from there.

Also vs code has still my old emulator open by default but i have delete this one like a month ago.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-a-flutter-app-on-android-emulator/amp/

Comment: Its something else i dont know, i cant even load flutter emulator without open android studio.That happens in React native projects too its not flutter-android problem.

Comment: so what do you see on the logs if you ruń your emulator directly from the command line?

Comment: I press the command pallete ,select device and i still have an old deleted emulator i dont know why . THen i select that emulator press Flutter run and it runs correctly. But i cant select any other emulator . When i try to create another one it says this : Error: Android Virtual Device 'flutter_emulator' already exists.

Comment: Just some commands i can press , some basic logs about java - dart VM etc . No errors ..